# jquery working in jsfiddle but not on a live website

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am working on a toggle function in jQuery on the page below. It works well when I try it out on jsfiddle but when I transfer to my site it deos not work. [Website here](http://goo.gl/xj4w3)

Below is the jQuery I'm working with.

```
$('a').click(function() {
/*    $(this).parent().next('.bios').toggle();*/
$('.bios').slideUp().fadeOut();
$(this).parent().next('.bios').animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
}, 300);
});
```

Comment: Did you check for jQuery conflicts? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: You're getting JS errors. . . Check your console first.

Comment: that site is giving me motion sickness...

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on your page... namely a `Function` instead of a `function`.